# Joining tables on Athena using a date and interval as key?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-athena, presto, trino

can i join tables on Athena using a date and a interval of dates as key parameter?

like this,

```
select *
from [table1] A
left join [table2] B on B.Date between A.Data_Begins and A.Data_Ends
```

Nothing, just trying to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Athena is based on Presto/Trino and at least the latter one supports it, try it yourself:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, dt_start, dt_end) as (
    values ('key1', date '2023-02-01', date '2023-02-10'),
           ('key3', date '2023-02-08', date '2023-03-10')
),
dataset2(num, dt) as (
    values (1, date '2023-02-01'),
           (2, date '2023-02-09'),
           (3, date '2023-03-10'),
           (4, date '2023-03-12')
)

-- query
select *
from dataset d 
left join dataset2 d2 on d2.dt between d.dt_start and d.dt_end;
```

Output:

| id | dt_start | dt_end | num | dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-10 | 1 | 2023-02-01 |
| key1 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-10 | 2 | 2023-02-09 |
| key3 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-03-10 | 2 | 2023-02-09 |
| key3 | 2023-02-08 | 2023-03-10 | 3 | 2023-03-10 |

Comment: Thank you, it really works! But if the dataset its too big it falls a part

Comment: @LucasSzalontai was glad to help. _"But if the dataset its too big it falls a part"_ - can you please provide more info, but actually not surprised because it basically "limited" cartesian product which can result in too much data.